# Python hex to binary fail

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert a hex string 'aa' to binary as following:

```
a = bin(int('aa',16))
```

But it gives me the error of:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#23>", line 1, in <module>
    a = bin(int('aa',16))
TypeError: bin(QTextStream): argument 1 has unexpected type 'int'
```

Can anyone explain what is the problem with the conversion?

Comment: Did you use `import *` anywhere in your code? Don't do that.

Comment: It is even fail when I try it in python IDLE....

Comment: Please see [Why is “import *” bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714/why-is-import-bad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did some sort of `import *`, probably

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
```

causing the built-in `bin` to be shadowed by a different function. Stop using `import *`, and the problem will go away.

Comment: @lwangreen: I Googled `bin QTextStream` and looked at your question history.